# Making the Waypoints jQuery plugin trigger when reaching the bottom only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-waypoints

I'm using the [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin to trigger something when the user reached the bottom of the page. Once the user reaches the bottom of the page, an AJAX call is triggered and I get a JSON response. Once this is done, the page size increases, meaning that we're not at the bottom of the page anymore (stuff gets added to the page), but still, the Waypoints plugin keeps repeating that AJAX call twice or thrice even though the bottom of the page is not there anymore, it's far below...

This is what I'm struggling to fix. I have tried a lot of ideas I thought of, but none worked. This is how I use the Waypoints plugin:

```
var pop_loader  = $('<br /><div class="loading row" style="display: none;"><div class="col-lg-12 center">' + 
    generate_preloader(32, 3) + '</div></div><br />');
var pop_footer  = $('.last-box-popular');
var pop_start   = { from: 24 };
var pop_opts    = { offset: '100%' };

pop_footer.waypoint(function(event, direction) {

    var $boxCount = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

    if ($boxCount.length < 24){
        return false;   
    }

    pop_footer.waypoint('destroy');
    $('.loadMore').append(pop_loader);
    $('.loading').fadeIn('slow');

    delay('pop', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'image.php?action=fetchMore&start=' + pop_start.from,
            success: function(data){

                try {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                } catch (e) {
                    display_alert(lang.L_TPL_AJAX_CATCH, 'danger', 3000, 'top');
                    return false;
                }

                if ('error' in response || $.isEmptyObject(response.images)) {
                    pop_loader.hide();
                    return false;
                }

                pop_start.from += 24;
                pop_loader.detach();
                pop_footer.waypoint(pop_opts);

                // Remove previous last class
                $('.image').removeClass('last-box-popular');
                var imagesLength = response.images.length - 1;

                for (var key in response.images) 
                {
                    var image = response.images[key];

                    var imageHTML = '<span class="image' + ((imagesLength == key) ? ' last-box-popular' : '') + '">';
                    imageHTML += '<div class="topleft-corner">';
                    imageHTML += '<div class="dropdown">';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="icon-share dropdown-toggle" id="share-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>';
                    imageHTML += '<ul class="dropdown-menu share-dropdown" role="menu" aria-labelledby="share-dropdown">';
                    imageHTML += '<li role="presentation">';
                    imageHTML += '<a href="' + generate_site_url() + 'store/t/' + image.image_name + '.' + image.image_extension + '" class="facebook_share" href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="icon-facebook-circled-2"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook';
                    imageHTML += '</a>';
                    imageHTML += '</li>';
                    imageHTML += '<li role="presentation">';
                    imageHTML += '<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=' + generate_site_url() + 'store/t/' + image.image_name + '.' + image.image_extension + '&amp;text=Shared via @IMGzer - " class="twitter_share" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="icon-twitter"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Twitter';
                    imageHTML += '</a>';
                    imageHTML += '</li>';
                    imageHTML += '<li role="presentation">';
                    imageHTML += '<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + generate_site_url() + 'store/t/' + image.image_name + '.' + image.image_extension + '" class="google_share" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="icon-gplus-circled-1"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Google+';
                    imageHTML += '</a>';
                    imageHTML += '</li>';
                    imageHTML += '</ul>';
                    imageHTML += '</div>';
                    imageHTML += '</div>';
                    imageHTML += '<div class="topright-corner">';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" title="Report" data-placement="left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#report" data-report="image" data-reference="' +  image.image_name + '"></span>';
                    imageHTML += '</div>';
                    imageHTML += '<section class="row">';
                    imageHTML += '<div class="col-lg-12 center upload-output">';
                    imageHTML += '<br /><br />';
                    imageHTML += '<div class="img-container">';
                    imageHTML += '<div class="helper"></div>';
                    imageHTML += '<a href="' + generate_site_url() + 'image/' + image.image_name + '">';
                    imageHTML += '<img src="' + generate_site_url() + 'store/t/' + image.image_name + '.' + image.image_extension + '" class="img-thumbnail">';
                    imageHTML += '</a>';
                    imageHTML += '</div>';
                    imageHTML += '<br />';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="small">Uploaded ' + image.upload_time + ' by <strong>' + ((image.username == null || image.username == '') ? 'a guest' : '<a href="' + generate_site_url() + 'user/' + image.username + '">' + image.username + '</a>') + '</strong></span>';
                    imageHTML += '<br />';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="label label-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> ' + image.image_likes + '</span>&nbsp;';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="label label-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> ' + image.image_dislikes + '</span>&nbsp;';
                    imageHTML += '<span class="label label-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> ' + image.image_favorited + '</span>';
                    imageHTML += '</div>';
                    imageHTML += '</section>';
                    imageHTML += '</span> ';

                    $('.images').append(imageHTML);
                    $('.image').slideDown('fast');
                }
            }
        });
    }, average_ajax_delay);

}, pop_opts); // Popular
```

How do I make the Waypoints plugin make **one AJAX call when reaching the bottom. then another AJAX call when the "new" bottom is reached**.

If there is anything additional needed to make this question clearer, please let me know.

Comment: Could you just set a timeout to ensure it doesn't call more than once within a set amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, it seems that trying to implement a standard AJAX call when reaching the bottom of the container is a bit buggy, even when I have tried to refresh waypoint's plugin using an internal function http://jsfiddle.net/f3YZ2/105/

Instead I have created a more elegant solution, I have placed a footer element at the very bottom of the page.
You may make it invisible using css like:

```
.footer{opacity:1;visibibility:hidden}
```

You should avoid hiding it as it would not be detected by the plugin:

Here is the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/f3YZ2/108/

Comment: Adding a "wait" lock to @Theodore's fiddle made it work for me in Chrome 35.0. [My fork of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUBdU/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of unbinding and then rebinding the waypoint, try [`$.waypoints('refresh');`](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#doc-refresh) after the new DOM elements have been inserted.

However, it may also be that the scrolling events are triggering multiple ajax calls which are making things act up. So you may need to [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) that function to prevent multiple calls before the request is responded to.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `triggerOnce: true` as an option when creating the waypoint.  In your `success` method, when you render additional elements to the DOM, add a new waypoint.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your trying to implement infinite scroll, so why not use the infinite scroll method of jQuery Waypoints: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/

Sure your server side implementation has to change, but the upside would be that the "more link could still be used by users who disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this sort of stuff before. The way I did was, I attached waypoints not to the last element that was added via ajax(lets call them **ajax items**) but to an element that is always in the DOM just below the last **ajax item**(lets call it **load more**). So you scroll down, waypoint hits **load more**, loads new content, which pushes **load more** down. So you can scroll again and hit **load more** again and trigger ajax. Worked pretty well for me.

Some tips:
1)You need to check that the direction is down before triggering your ajax call.
2) When you click back button and go to the page, waypoint might trigger on page load. If you need to prevent this check the scroll event before firing your ajax call. Watch out the browser will automatically trigger a scroll event if there was any scroll on the page before, so you trigger your waypoint/ajax on the second and later scrolls events only.

Simple code example(I was using jQuery, but you will get the idea);

```
$('.load-more').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down' && content.o.scroll > 1) {
         // Do your stuff here
    }

}, {offset: '170%'});

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    content.o.scroll++;
});
```